# Oracle Loop through values from one table and join with another table

Tags: oracle-11g-r2

I have a table (`table1`) with fields `package_id` and `contract_id`.

Data in table 1 is like that 1 `package_id` can have 1 or more `contract_id` associated with it.

I have another table (`table2`) with `contract_id` and `status`. status can be (`'active'` or `'dead'`)

I need to find the `package_id` which doesn't have any `contract_id` associated with it which is `'ACTIVE'` or in other words I need to find `package_id` which has all `contract_id` associated with it in `'DEAD'` state.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do this would be with `NOT EXISTS` with an `INNER JOIN` or `MINUS`

**INNER JOIN**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT t2.contract_id
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t3
ON t3.contract_id = t2.contract_id
WHERE t2.status = 'ACTIVE' 
AND t3.package_id = t1.package_id
);
```

**MINUS**

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 t1
WHERE EXISTS
(
SELECT t2.contract_id
FROM table2 t2
WHERE t2.status = 'ACTIVE' 
MINUS
SELECT t3.contract_id 
FROM table1 t3
WHERE t3.package_id = t1.package_id
);
```

[DB <> Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=469a2561a80905a7e79f815dcc65f7ff)